# Where can I get the Compiz-Check tool?

Tags: compiz

I red about this tool but the source website is offline

Where can I find this tool?

**More Info:** 
This is example of the use of Compiz-Check http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/check-if-compiz-will-run-well-on-your-linux-box-with-compiz-check/

This is the source but it is offline http://forlong.blogage.de/article/pages/Compiz-Check

Thanks

Comment: Is it this? `/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -pc`

Comment: No, this http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1499321

Comment: It's no longer developed. Would another application be okay?

Comment: Hi @RolandiXor, yes of course